# Concatenate two column in python

Tags: python, csv

Good day,

I want to concatenate two columns from a csv file and put this string into another csv file but into a single column.

Code that I tried:

```
import csv

file1=open('Source.csv','r') 
readfile=csv.reader(file1,delimiter=';')
file2=open('Output.csv','w',newline='')
result=()
for row in readfile:
    if (row[2]>condition1 and 'string' in row[6]):          
        result=str(row[2])+'- '+str(row[6])
        print(result)#line just to see to info from the output file
        writefile=csv.writer(file2,delimiter=';')
        writefile.writerow(result)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

My issue is that the `result` is not wrote in a single column into the output file ,but each character is wrote in a separate column.

Note that the `print()`seems to be what I want to put in the output file.

Some help in this way?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

file1=open('Source.csv','r') 
readfile=csv.reader(file1,delimiter=';')
file2=open('Output.csv','w',newline='')
writefile=csv.writer(file2,delimiter=';')
result=()
for row in readfile:
  if (row[2]>condition1 and 'string' in row[6]):          
    result=[str(row[2])+'- '+str(row[6])]
    print(result)#line just to see to info from the output file
    writefile.writerow(result)

file1.close()
file2.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand on Rahul's answer, I highly recommend the use of ContextManager (`with`). It ensures your files will be closed propery even if an exception occurs when processing them.

Like this:

```
import csv

with open('Source.csv') as file1:
    readfile = csv.reader(file1,delimiter=';')
    with open('Output.csv','w',newline='') as file2:
        writefile = csv.writer(file2,delimiter=';')
        for row in readfile:
              if row[2] > condition1 and 'string' in row[6]:          
                  result = [str(row[2]) + '- ' + str(row[6])]
                  print(result)#line just to see to info from the output file
                  writefile.writerow(result)
```